# How find data from JSON using python and watson discovery news

Tags: python, json, watson-discovery

```
{
  "matching_results": 1264,
  "results": [
    {
      "main_image_url": "https://s4.reutersmedia.net/resources_v2/images/rcom-default.png",
      "enriched_text": {
        "entities": [
          {
            "relevance": 0.33,
            "disambiguation": {
              "subtype": [
                "Country"
              ]
            },
            "sentiment": {
              "score": 0
            },
            "type": "Location",
            "count": 1,
            "text": "China"
          },
          {
            "relevance": 0.33,
            "disambiguation": {
              "subtype": [
                "Country"
              ]
            },
            "sentiment": {
              "score": 0
            },
```

This is too much large file so I want to find "relevance" and "score" using python.
How fetch this info?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of how large it is, it is only a simple dictionary.

Iterate the lists. Extract the key-values.

```
for result in data['results']:
    for e in result['enriched_text']['entities']:
        print(e['relevance'])
        print(e['sentiment']['score'])
```

Comment: sir, I use this code but on entities error occur ..KeyError: 'entities'

Comment: Well, do you know how to fix the problem? I've given 90% of the solution

Comment: Sir am new on json, I try much but not found solution

Comment: If you tried things, you should actually include them in the question. Anyways, I edited my answer. Parsing your JSON is no different from any other... Learn how to read `[]` vs `{}`, change the strings, and its all the same. Once you understand that, you can parse JSON in any language